# Android - How to save checkbox state (checked/unchecked) after changing activity

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox, adapter

I have searched through StackOverflow, but have not found a proper answer yet.

I have created a `ListView` (iteration of a `checkbox` + `itemview`) and populated it through my customAdapter (which extends *BaseAdapter*).

I have a button which takes the values and print it on the screen via a Toast.

So far, so good.

Next step, I still have the button in the `MainActivity`, but the `ListView` is now in a child activity that I reach by clicking an image (`ImageView` placed in the `MainActivity`). I can still check the checkboxes, but I face two issues:

1. I am still not able to pass the values to the `MainActivity`, where they will be printed on screen (or manipulated)
2. As soon as I press the back button to go back to the `MainActivity` and I press again the image, every `CheckBox` that was checked is not checked anymore (they came back to default state)

I don't think that code is needed, as it comes from a standard implementation (`ListView` - `customAdapter` with `ViewHolder` implementation, ...), but in case just let me know.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can put which checkboxes are checked into sharedpreferences. Then move the listview initialization code to Activity's `onResume` method.

**Sample** class to handle `sharedpreferences` data:

```
class DataHandler {

    private final SharedPreferences dataStore;

    DataHandler(Context mContext) {
        dataStore = mContext.getSharedPreferences("appname", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    int which() {
        return  dataStore.getInt("some_key",0);
    }

    void setCheckedItem(int itemwhat) {
        dataStore.edit().putInt("some_key",itemwhat).apply();
    }
}
```

For multiple values, you can put them into an array then convert them to string using `toString()` method and save. And, to get the values:

```
String x = "2,3,4,5"; //assume
String[] y = new String[]{x};
int checkablepositions = Integer.parseInt(y[0]); // y[0]....y[y.length-1]
```

Now, at MainActivity's `onResume()`, Assume that you have initialized ListView as 'mainList'.

```
CheckBox x1y2z3 = (CheckBox)mainList.getChildAt(new DataHandler(getBaseContext).which());
x1y2z3.setChecked(true);
```

And for Saving item,

I would recommend you to *show them in an alert-dialog* instead of in a Toast. Then set a Positive button to get the values from below code and save them.

Or, if you directly save the values from listview `onClick` :

```
mainList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {
           new DataHandler(getBaseContext()).setCheckedItem(position);              
          }
        });
```

That's it. I'm really new at programming (as you can see my StackOverFlow rep) but hope it will be able to help you.

The main concept is to : store the value → get the value → parse the value → show it on UI.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
I am not able to place your code into my program. Probably it's my fault. I am going to add some details to my question, I hope it helps.
Basically, I do not need to retrieve the values (I have created a DataModel class for it), but the issue is to pass those values/object from the child activity to the main activity.
And, I also need to save the checkbox state in a way that if I need to come back to the child activity, the checbox keep their state (checked or unchecked) until the app is closed.